# Jquery implementing a success and error callback for my plugin that works with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I have written a small Jquery plugin that makes it easy for me to implement Facebook like "likes" on any item in my application. My only issue now is that I struggle to implement the success / error callback of my plugin.

```
$('.user-like').like({
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(this).text('Liked');
    }
});
```

My issue with the above code is this line:

```
$(this).text('Liked');
```

I'm aware of what why the issue happens, I just can't find a good way to make it work like I want it. Let me explain how the script works and what my Goal is:

As you can see I'm passing the call along to the likeApi() function that executes an AJAX call. Further you see that I merge my Options with the defaults and that you can override the success and error callback of the AJAX object.

The issue is now that `this` in the above code is the scope of the AJAX call and *not* my original method. I want to allow the user to define his own success / error callback that depends on the result of the API call and allows me to do something based on the state if it was a success or failure so that I can change the like text for example. How can I do this?

```
(function ($) {

    $.likeApi = function (action, options) {
        if (action != 'like' && action != 'unlike') {
            return false;
        }
        var options = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.likeApi.defaults, options);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: options.baseUrl + action + '.json',
            data: {
                data: {
                    Like: {
                        foreign_key: options.id,
                        model: options.model
                    }
                }
            },
            success: options.success,
            error: options.error,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    };

    $.fn.like = function (options) {
        var scopedOptions = options;
        this.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.likeApi('like', $.extend({}, scopedOptions,{
                'id': $(event.target).data('like-fk'),
                'model': $(event.target).data('like-model')
            }));
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.unlike = function (options) {
        var scopedOptions = options;
        this.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var result = $.likeApi('unlike', $.extend({}, scopedOptions,{
                'id': $(event.target).data('like-fk'),
                'model': $(event.target).data('like-model')
            }));
            alert(result);
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.likeApi.defaults = {
        baseUrl: '/likes/likes/',
        action: null,
        model: null,
        id: null,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options: you can maintain context by adding a variable that references the original `this`, or you can use jquery.proxy()

**Option 1**:
Maintain the context by adding a variable that references the original `this` like so:

```
(function ($) {
    $.likeApi = function (action, options) {
        var self = this;
```

Then you just call `self` whenever you are out of context.

If you want to keep `self` available externally, you can `inject` it using jquery extend.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

```
options.success = $.extend(options.sucesss, {el: self});
```

inside your ajax call

```
$('.user-like').like({
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(data.el).text('Liked');
    }
});
```

**Option 2**:
Alternatively, you can use jQuery.proxy()
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/

proxy can change the `this` context for you...

Comment: Thank you, but I'm always getting "undefined" for Option 1, see http://pastebin.com/xQhwW6eq.